# Учебник по алгоритмам на Objective-C

Tags: алгоритм, objective-c, книги

Что-нибудь типа Сэджвика...

Comment: С английским проблем нет? Тогда Programming in Objective-C 2.0 (3nd Edition) by Stephen G. Kochan. Если проблемы есть - надо их устранять, так как с Obj-C придется много чего искать на зарубежных форумах.

Comment: Не не верен на счет издания, но книга есть и на русском : http://www.labirint.ru/books/249410/ Вот только алгоритмов в ней я что-то не помню, скорее это хороший учебник по языку и его стандартной библиотеке классов

Comment: @aknew да и правда, совсем забыл (там, конечно, предыдущее издательство, но не суть). А алгоритмы вообще не зависят от ЯП, насколько я понимаю.

Comment: да не зависят)) мне интересны реализации на  Objective-C..

Comment: @pol если вы знаете язык, то и любую реализацию сами напишите, разве нет?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Небольшой философский экскурс

Да, знания любого программиста, безусловно, должны включать в себя и теорию алгоритмов и знания языка. Но покупать книги с запрошенным вами названием, это всё равно, что покупать «Язык С++ и рыболовное дело для терминаторов». Согласитесь вещи не очень связанные. Так что советую вам преобрести одну нормальную книгу по Objective-C и одну по алгоритмам.

---

Далее по степени вашей подготовленности сверху вниз.

##### Алгоритмы:

1. Кнут — «Искусство программирования»;
2. Кормен — «Алгоритмы: построение и анализ»;
3. Вирт — «Алгоритмы и структуры данных».

##### Objective-C:

1. Стивен Кочан — «Программирование на Objective-C 2.0»;
2. Марк Далримпл, Скотт Кнастер — «Objective-C 2.0 и программирование для Mac».

Comment: Кормена я читал, Кнута листал. Просто хочу поучить язык на реализациях алгоритмов с учетом нюансов Ojective-C. 
PS я бы с удовольствием почитал «Язык С++ и рыболовное дело для терминаторов» ))))

Answer (score 1):

[The Objective-C Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html).

XD

Comment: это скорее не учебник по языку)

Comment: Я думаю, что этот сайт для тех, кто уже имеет базовые знания по программированию хотя - бы в C++

Comment: хе-хе, я знаю базовые языки программировния (вплоть до основ ассемблера)))
это не то чего я хотел, да и читал я оттуда кое-что..